# Calculate the derivative and sketch the graph for $f(x) = \arctan \frac{x-1}{x+1} + \arctan \frac{x+1}{x-1}$, $x \neq -1,1$

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

A function is given as
$$f(x) = \arctan \frac{x-1}{x+1} + \arctan \frac{x+1}{x-1}, x \neq -1,1$$
and I am supposed to calculate the derivative and sketch the graph.

I calculate the derivative like
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \arctan \frac{x-1}{x+1} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{x-1}{x+1} \right)^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2+1}\\
\frac{d}{dx} \arctan \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^2 +1} \cdot \left( -\frac{2}{(x-1)^2} \right) = -\frac{1}{x^2+1}\\
\frac{d}{dx} \arctan \frac{x-1}{x+1} + \arctan \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{x^2+1} = 0$$

And understand that the function has zero slope. How would I go about sketching its graph?

Since it is undefined in $x = -1,1$ I think that I am supposed to treat it as three cases, and calculate the $y$-value of all 3, then just draw 3 straight lines. Is this correct? How can I motivate it?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and (if that's what you mean by 'motivate') your description already contains all the necessary reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result (zero slope) is correct everywhere as  *an identity*

Alternately we attempt to simplify, sketch the graph and then calculate derivative.

Let $ y= \tan^{-1}\dfrac{x-1}{x+1} $

$$f(x)=y+\dfrac{1}{y}= \tan^{-1}\dfrac{...} {0} = \tan^{-1}\infty=\dfrac {\pi}{2} + k \pi$$

which includes co-terminal angles which are odd multiples of $\pi/2.$  The constant function  $ y=f(x)$ is sketched.

[image: constants odd right angles]

All the $f(y)$ are constants. Accordingly all derivatives vanish.

Either way result is the same.

Comment: OP certainly shouldn't write, e.g., $\tan^{-1} \frac{\cdots}{0}$ on an assignment (and OP's phrasing suggests the problem occurs in that context).

Comment: For that matter, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan^{-1} x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so there's no immediate justification for the mnemonic "$\tan^{-1} (\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi$".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It is well known that $$\arctan x+\arctan \frac 1x=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}\frac\pi2&\text{if } x>0, \\[1ex]-\frac\pi2&\text{if } x<0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: And if someone doesn't know this, it's easy to see: For $x > 0$ this follows from drawing a right triangle with leg lengths $1, x$, and for $x < 0$ it follows from the $x > 0$ case and the fact that the expression is manifestly odd in $x$.

Comment: Anyway, a function with a $0$ derivative is constant on each interval  contained in its domain (i.e. it is locally constant).